# Merge Replication API with SQL Server 2012 / 2014

Tags: merge-replication

We are using SQL Server 2008 with merge replication. Our business application uses the RMO API, which we have installed with SQL Server Feature Pack 2008 SP3 and there the package `sql_rmo.msi`.

Now we want use SQL Server 2012 or 2014. In SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack, I can not find such a package.

How can I install the `RMO` libs for SQL Server 2012 / 2014?

Answer (score 1):

The RMO API is deprecated from SQL Server 2012 and onwards. Microsoft suggests using T-SQL instead.